# How can I access the Objects created in an Action Method inside OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of data fetched form database. Now I want to filter the list based on some conditions. I want to do the filtering in my Filter. So how can I access any object that is created in the Action Method inside the

```
OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext){
        // I want to access objects created in Action Method here ...
}
```

How can I do this please tell.

Comment: Objects means by variables?

Comment: For example if I create something like this : 
var data = context.FetchServiceDetails();

//now I want to access data in my Filter so that I can modify it prior to sending to view

Comment: you can store in `viewbag`, `viewdata` or `tempdata` and get in filter from same

Comment: is there any other way of doing it for example by using filterContex reference ? -Thanks

Comment: the TempData doesnot exist in the filterContext

Comment: ohkey great, by the way it can access by filterContext.Controller.TempData

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionexecutedcontext.result%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

> ActionExecutedContext.Result Property
>   Gets or sets the result returned by the action method.

So try to check `filterContext.Result` or `filterContext.RequestContext` if there is any value/object you need.

If not, you have to send that object via `TempData[..]` or some `Session[..]` in your `ActionResult` method in controller, and then intercept it in your filter method.